# Maya Python: How do I get the scene name but not the path or extension

Tags: python, maya

I want to get just the scene name of the file that is currently open. Not the path or extension.

```
cmds.file(q=True, sn=True)
```

I cannot use the above as it returns the full path.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure but google led me [here](http://forums.cgsociety.org/archive/index.php?t-1075963.html) and the answer there is `cmds.file(query=True, l=True)[0]`

Comment: i also found this https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/maya-programming/query-scene-name/td-p/7405265

Answer (score 8):

the `os` module includes utilities for this:

```
 filepath = cmds.file(q=True, sn=True)
 filename = os.path.basename(filepath)
 raw_name, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
```

Answer (score 2):

*(I wanted to post this as a comment to **theodox**'s answer, but I can't as I don't have the required reputation level)*

**theodox**'s answer is the correct answer (using the Python 'os' module):

```
filepath = cmds.file(q=True, sn=True)
filename = os.path.basename(filepath)
raw_name, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
```

You can make it shorter by combining with **Serious Sam**'s answer (which gives the file name with extension, but in a single instruction instead of 2 as in **theodox**'s answer):

```
filename = cmds.file(q=True, sn=True, shn=True)
raw_name, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

cmds.file(q=True, sn=True, shn=True)

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
# a= "Full File Path of the scene"
a= r"C:\Python36\Lib\site-packages\anytree\node\nodemixin.py"

print(os.path.split(a)[1].split('.')[0])
```

> > > 'nodemixin'

## or

```
print(os.path.splitext(a)[0].split('\\')[-1])
```

> > > 'nodemixin'

Comment: // Error: name 'a' is not defined
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 12, in <module>
# NameError: name 'a' is not defined //

Comment: Corrected the mistake, the variable name is the a

Comment: I made it a little more convenient by doing this 

filePath = cmds.file(q=True, sn=True)
print(os.path.split(filePath)[1].split('.')[0])

Comment: this gets the full path using a maya command then just splits it with your handy code

Comment: Use `os.path` methods instead! They work cross-platforms and are a lot more readable.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Python in Maya you can use the `file` command. When you split it based on `/` you will get a list as result, which you then just count from the rear [-1]. That gives you the current Maya scene file name as string.

```
cmds.file(q=True, sn=True).split('/')[-1]
```

Comment: Same as Surya's answer, use `os.path` methods instead so that it's cross-platform friendly. -1

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

scene = cmds.file(q=True, sn=True)

scene = scene.split('/')[-1]

print(scene)
```